# Как передать данные из Custom layout в activity layout?

Tags: android, dialogfragment

Это `custom layout` не знаю как передать данные на другой `activity`(который не является `MainActivity`) тут я передаю количество в корзину. Корзина находится в `((Dialog_lay1)getActivity()).txt_siparis1.setText(input); //???`
плиз помогите и спасибо за уделенное время.

```
public class Asma1 extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
public TextView adet_asma;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View mview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.asma1, null);
adet_asma = mview.findViewById(R.id.text_value);

mview.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonPlus).setOnClickListener(v -> {
TvPlus_Minus++;
adet_asma.setText(String.valueOf(TvPlus_Minus));
});

mview.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonMinus).setOnClickListener(v -> {
TvPlus_Minus--;
adet_asma.setText(String.valueOf(TvPlus_Minus));
});

mview.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonclose1).setOnClickListener(v -> {
dismiss(); //close dialog
});

mview.findViewById(R.id.on_siparis).setOnClickListener(v -> {
String input = adet_asma.getText().toString();
if(!input.equals("")) {
**((Dialog_lay1)getActivity()).txt_siparis1.setText(input);** //???
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "заказ добавлен в список", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
dismiss();
}
else{
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"o", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
});
return mview;

//////////////////////////////////Dialog_lay1//////////////////
public class Dialog_lay1 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
ImageButton close_dialog;
public TextView txt_siparis1;
public TextView adi_asma1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.dialog_lay1);
close_dialog = findViewById(R.id.close_dialog);
close_dialog.setOnClickListener(this);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

txt_siparis1 = findViewById(R.id.text_siparis);
adi_asma1 = findViewById(R.id.adet1);
```

Comment: Объяви глобальную переменную public static String и через неё передавай

Comment: Сейчай проверю, спасибо.

Comment: ((Dialog_lay1)getActivity()).txt_siparis1.setText(input); проблема тут, приложение крашится